# Which one is more expensive to compute: 1) $(A^TDA + \mu I)^{-1} x$, 2)$A^TDA y$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, diagonal $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

I am wondering, which one is more expensive to compute (in terms of multiplications):

1). $\left(A^TDA + \mu I\right)^{-1} x$

2). $A^TDA y$,

where matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, diagonal matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, and $\mu$ is a scalar.

---

My take is that 1) is more expensive to compute than 2).

- The worst-case complexity of matrix-matrix product of $A^TDA$ is $O(m^2n)$. Correct?
- Worst-case complexity cost for 1) would be $O(m^2n + m^3 + m^2n)$, where $m^3$ is due to matrix inversion and $m^2n$ is due to matrix-vector product. Correct?
- Worst-case complexity cost for 2) would be $O(mn)$. [See comment from JimmyK4542]
- Further, one could also parallelise the matrix-matrix-vector product operations. However, the matrix inversion can not be parallelised. Agree?

Comment: Unless you're looking for an answer whose entire content is "yes", you should tell us why it is that you doubted this enough to post a question about it

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment. I am unsure, in particular, about the 4th bullet point.

Comment: The cost for (2) should be $O(mn)$ since computing $Ay$ from $y$ takes $O(mn)$ operations, computing $DAy$ from $Ay$ takes $O(n)$ operations, and computing $A^TDAy$ from $DAy$ takes $O(mn)$ operations.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thank you for the feedback. You are right.

Comment: @learning It is an open problem whether matrix-matrix multiplication and matrix inversion of $n\times n$ can be done in nearly $O(n^2)$ time. The best lower bound in $\Omega(n^2 \log n)$ by Raz. If $\mu$ is sufficiently large relative to the entries in $A$ and $D$, then $(A^\top D A + \mu I)^{-1}x$ can be computed in $O(m \log^{1/2} m \log^c \log m)$ time using techniques from spectral graph theory once $A^\top D A + \mu I$ has been computed. If $\mu > 0$, it remains an open problem whether ($A^\top DA+\mu I)^{-1}x$ can be computed fast.

Comment: If $n \ll m$, you may consider usingthe Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury matrix identity to multiply by the inverse of  $A^\top D A + \mu I$, which I believe takes $O(mn^2+n^3)$ operations.

Comment: @eepperly16 Thank you for your comments. I follow your first comment. However, I am not sure whether I have understood your second comment.

Comment: $(\mu I + A^\top D A)^{-1}x = \mu^{-1}x - \mu^{-2} A^\top (D^{-1}+\mu^{-1}AA^\top)^{-1}Ax$. The both term can be evaluated using only $O(mn^2+n^3)$ operations. In particular $D^{-1}+\mu^{-1}AA^\top$ can be assembled in $O(mn^2)$ operations and inverted in $O(n^3)$ operations.

Comment: @eepperly16 Thank you. I appreciate it.